# Unable to plot JSON to chartJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, chart.js

I'm trying to plot a dataset into a chartJS line chart:

This is my data:

```
[{"close":0.00786609},{"close":0.00784},{"close":0.00784},
 {"close":0.00780507},{"close":0.007816},{"close":0.00781599},
 {"close":0.00780166},{"close":0.00778403},{"close":0.00782001},
 {"close":0.0078},{"close":0.00778},{"close":0.007799},
 {"close":0.00775057},{"close":0.0077688},{"close":0.00775001}]
```

This is my code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'line',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {

        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: <%= JSON.stringify(prices) %>,
        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {}
});
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured your chart to be of type "line". The [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#data-structure) for this type specifies that a dataset's `data` can be an Array of Numbers or an Array of Points, where a Point is an Object with a `x` property and a `y` property.

Your `data` is a JSON stringified Array of objects, each with a `close` property.

You need to map your `prices` Array into an Array of Numbers. In JavaScript, this could be done as:

```
prices.map(function (price) {
    return price.close;
});
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/35skjy15/) as an example.